# How can I reorder columns in wordpress for different screen sizes

Tags: wordpress, responsive-design

In wordpress I have a row with default coulms like:
|A|B|C| 
How can I make it display for small screens like this:
|B|
|A|
|C|
I dont have any problem with responsive design. I just cannot figure how to reorder columns on different screen sizes.
I need something equivalent of bootstrap pull/push.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Simplest way is to create two set of your elements by your desire order.

name your sets A which is |A|B|C| and B which is 
|B|
|A|
|C|
.

A will show in larger screen sizes and B will show in smaller.

something like this :
A Set :

```
<div class='container A-Set'>
   <div class='A' style='float : right'>
     A
   </div>
   <div class='B' style='float : right'>
     B
   </div>
   <div class='C' style='float : right'>
     C
   </div>
   <div style='clear : both'></div>
</div>
```

B Set :

```
<div class='container B-Set'>
   <div class='B'>
     B
   </div>
   <div class='A'>
     A
   </div>
   <div class='C'>
     C
   </div>
</div>
```

Stylesheet :

```
@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {
    container.B-Set {
        display : none
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    container.A-Set {
        display : none
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I do not think it is good practice to repeat containers. It would mess with search engines also.

Comment: I said, the simplest way.